# Syntax highlighting fails to highlight "abstract" correctly

Tags: bug, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

I've just noticed that the syntax highlighting no longer highlights C# "`abstract`" keyword correctly:

> [Is this an abuse of the type system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1540070/is-this-an-abuse-of-the-type-system/1540083#1540083)

I think it used to work correctly before. Anything changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we deployed a new Google prettify.js a few days ago; maybe it's their bug?

Edit: deployed yet another prettify.js.

Comment: That explains some other weirdness I've been seeing with XML highlighting -- specifically WPF and ASPX code, Google's prettify seems to be miscoloring initial caps on attribute names.

Comment: Probably. I guess you should revert to the old version, considering the dominance of C# on StackOverflow.

Comment: nah, we'll just wait for a new release from prettify. Users requested this version, search meta for the reference.

Comment: @Mehrdad: While C# is very prevalent, there are a **lot** of other languages represented on SO, and like @Jeff says, people have been asking for prettify updates a lot lately. I agree with him; wait til the next upgrade which will hopefully rectify the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed at revision 87: http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/source/diff?spec=svn87&r=87&format=side&path=/trunk/src/prettify.js